# VB.NET | How to set datasource of Sub-Report inside a Sub-Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Hello I am trying to add a data source of a sub report inside a sub report.
I already done setting the data source of a sub report like this

```
cryRpt.SetDataSource(dsBasicInfo)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg1Col.rpt").SetDataSource(dsBasicInfo)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg2.rpt").SetDataSource(dsRationale)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg2FH.rpt").SetDataSource(dsFHIncome)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg2Exp.rpt").SetDataSource(dsFHExpense)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg2CashInflow.rpt").SetDataSource(dsFinancialHL)
cryRpt.Subreports("Pg3.rpt").SetDataSource(dsBasis)
```

but inside the Pg1Col.rpt I also have a subreport. That I want to add a data source

Comment: Sorry. Apparently it is not possible to add a sub-report inside another sub-report in Crystal Reports, as what this article says. [1293388 - How to add a subreport inside another subreport in Crystal Reports?](https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1293388)

Comment: Yep, there's no other way, so I have to re design my report in order to achieve my desired output